# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `ParentViewController`, I have

```
    [some_vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc.someData = data;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

I get following message in logs

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   ParentViewController: 0x7ff118750d50.

If I change to "NO" to "YES"

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I do not see the message.

What could be the issue. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: The issue occurs if you push a new view controller with animated option while previous transaction (animation) is in progress. You need to ensure that previous transaction is complete, before you push your view controller. @rmaddy as answered one of the ways to achieve it other way would be delaying next transaction by few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is was the completion handler is for. Try this:

```
[some_vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc.someData = data;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}];
```

This ensures the new controller isn't presented until the previous one has finished dismissing.

Another option would be to reverse the order:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
vc.someData = data;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
[some_vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This pushes the new controller and then dismisses the modal. The advantage of this is the new one is visible as the modal is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks you very much again. The "Another option" is what works for me for the advantage you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the UITabBarController and forgot to call the super of viewWillAppear. So the transition animation of the UITabBarController not finished.

This caused the the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance"!

Answer (score -1):

U need add loadView.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:NO];
[self.navigationController loadView];
```